# Is this property equivalent to the antisymmetric property for relations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request, vector-spaces, order-theory

I was trying to prove that a certain relation ($\leq$) in a real vector space is a partial order, and I lack the antisymmetric property. However, I have been able to prove the following statement:

If $-\alpha I \leq W \leq \alpha I$ for every $\alpha > 0$ then $W=0$.

Is that condition equivalent to the antisymmetric property? If so, does anyone know how to prove that equivalence or know of any reference where it is done? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you say they are equivalent in the first place?

Comment: @Zima I don't understand your question, sorry. If they are equivalent or not is what I am asking. Thanks

Comment: I'm asking what makes you think they could be equivalent